# htmlentities won't convert into html

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and I am trying to use

htmlentities but he won't print it as HTML

```
$string2 = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
echo htmlentities($string2);
```

he just print it as `<h1>Hello</h1>`

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you view source what do you see? It should be https://3v4l.org/0eRUW

Comment: its just showing <h1>Hello</h1> as text

Answer (score 0):

[htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php) aims to escape special characters to display them instead of interpreting them. If you want your browser interprets HTML tags, you just have to echo the HTML code.

```php
$string2 = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
echo $string2;
```